# Presentation: shout-out to contributors at the beginning or the end?

Tags: presentations

In a slides presentation, what's your opinion on the timing for this shout-out?

I think at the beginning is better as you can draw the attention of them in audience.

Comment: What context? Business meeting, convention, after work social gathering, ... wedding? (The last one is probably a very bad choice.)  It sounds like you're probably talking convention, but I feel this is probably important for the answer to consider...

Answer (score 4):

> what's your opinion on the timing for this shout-out?
>
> I think at the beginning is better as you can draw the attention of
>   them in audience.

No.

Shout outs go at the end of the presentation - after you have gone through the details of what you are presenting.

Only at the end will viewers understand the context of your praise.

Comment: In addition to this, the first few minutes of any presentation are when you invite your audience to invest their attention in the rest of the presentation. If you're just  reading a list of names, people's minds are going to start wandering before the presentation has even started. The audience will care more about the contributors if the presentation itself impresses them. Putting the names up front may come across as sycophancy - like you care more about ingratiating yourself to the people you're name-checking than making a good impression on your audience.

Answer (score 2):

If four people did the work, and you're presenting it for whatever reason, the four of you should stand up at the front, the first slide should have all four names on it, and you should introduce yourself followed by each of your team-mates. They can either continue to stand up there (especially if they might answer questions) or step aside and sit down during your presentation, according to the team's preference.

If you did the work, and are doing the presentation, but want to thank someone who helped a lot, you can do it at the end but it is probably better to do it in context as it happens. "Here are some lovely graphs, prepared by Steve Jones - point to him and smile - that clearly show …". Even for acknowledgements at the end, try to include what specifically they did that you are acknowledging. For example "this has also been ported to the Mac by Ellen McInroy" and "we have a twitter account also that Chris Dunphy is running."

Answer (score 1):

If you have specific points in the presentation where an individual contributed heavily, do it right at that point.

> I need to thank  for showing me this trick, it's saved me countless hours while editing content

If it's just general "these folks really helped me out", do it at the end. Otherwise, your audience will be wondering why they're in the room listening to you when they could be listening to those other people, or they'll be puzzled as to the relevance of those shout-outs and not paying attention to you as you go through the presentation.